# How can I smoothly transition between two color animation loops in React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

Let's say I'm running an animation loop between green and blue (well there are more colors along the interpolation but I start off cycling between the first three):

```
this.state = {
  colorValue: new Animated.Value(0)
};
this.interpolations = {
  background: this.state.colorValue.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 25, 50, 75, 100],
    outputRange: ["#64e5a5", "#216a7a", "#64e5a5", "#ffb637", "#ffd338"]
  })
};
this.backgroundAnimation = Animated.loop(
  Animated.timing(this.state.colorValue, {
    toValue: 50,
    duration: 10000
  })
);
this.backgroundAnimation.start();
```

Note that I set up extra colors along that interpolation hoping I could just stop the animation loop and start a new one cycling between 75 and 100 for smooth transition between the two color cycles. When I modify this code for the desired effect, the animation seems to always start from 0. I tried setting the animated value to 50 but that didn't fix anything. Can someone explain the right way to do this?

Note: The above code doesn't include an attempt to actually switch to the next color cycle because I really don't have any clue how to do it.

Edit: I'm getting close, but not quite there, the second loop doesnt work:

```
  this.backgroundAnimation.stop();
  this.interpolations.background = this.state.colorValue.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 100],
    outputRange: [JSON.stringify(this.interpolations.background), "#ffd338"]
  });

  Animated.timing(this.state.colorValue, {
    toValue: 100,
    duration: 3000
  }).start(() => {
    console.log("Done");
    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      colorValue : new Animated.Value(0) //just spit-balling, idk
    });
    this.interpolations.background = this.state.colorValue.interpolate({
      inputRange: [0, 50, 100],
      outputRange: ["#ffd338", "#fff39b", "#ffd338"]
    });
    console.log(this.interpolations.background);


    this.backgroundAnimation = Animated.loop(
      Animated.timing(this.state.colorValue, {
        toValue: 100,
        duration: 3000
      })
    );
    this.backgroundAnimation.start();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out :)

```
this.backgroundAnimation.stop();
  this.setState({
    ...this.state,
    interpolations: {
      ...this.state.interpolations,
      background: this.state.colorValue.interpolate({
        inputRange: [0, 100],
        outputRange: [
          JSON.stringify(this.state.interpolations.background),
          "#ffd338"
        ]
      })
    }
  });
  Animated.timing(this.state.colorValue, {
    toValue: 100,
    duration: 2000
  }).start(() => {
    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      interpolations: {
        ...this.state.interpolations,
        background: this.state.colorValue.interpolate({
          inputRange: [0, 50, 100],
          outputRange: ["#ffd338", "#ffffff", "#ffd338"]
        })
      }
    });
    this.backgroundAnimation = Animated.loop(
      Animated.timing(this.state.colorValue, {
        toValue: 100,
        duration: 2000
      })
    );
    this.backgroundAnimation.start();
  });
});
```

Comment: I think it can technically be done more simply than this, but if you want to go straight to a specific color range, the re-interpolate step with `JSON.stringify(this.state.interpolations.background)` is necessary I think. I'm still scratching my head about why I have to stringify that lol.